# Pass Parameters using <httpRedirect> in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-config, parameter-passing, http-redirect

In my ASP.Net website I am permanently redirecting an URL to other location using `<httpRedirect>` in web config.
I am reading URL value from table and redirecting to that URL using `Response.Redirect( URL );`
It is working perfect.
But now when I try to send the parameter to the calling page using:

```
Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?name=stackoverflow");
```

`<httpRedirect>` in web.config calles the `Default2.aspx` because of following code in web.config:

```
<location path="Default.aspx">
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="Default2.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

The Problem is `Default2.aspx` does not receive any parameters.
Please help.

**Note:** I cannot use session variable as page contents depends on that parameter.

For instance,
If user opens another page in new tab with `Default.aspx?name=MetaStackOverflow` session variable will get replaced and if first page is refreshed then instead of showing `Stackoverflow` content it will show `MetaStackOverflow`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't forget the special characters $V$Q and the exactDestination has to be set to True.

`<location path="Help">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/Redirect.aspx$V$Q" httpResponseStatus="Permanent" exactDestination="true" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>`

Comment: It is now sending the URL parameters but the page is getting called 3 to 4 times and my css on `Default2.aspx` are not applied. What does these special characters "$V$Q" indicates ?

Comment: @user1808827: $V is for URL path and $Q for QueryString.
You cam use ` destination="/Redirect.aspx$Q"` to pass only querystring

Comment: Do you have a web resource that lists all of these keywords/variables like `$V` and `$Q`?